# What is on-topic on GenAI SE?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

TL;DR: The site scope is still being discussed. The starting point is included as [answer](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2/806) to this question, but there are other related questions. See [site-scope](/questions/tagged/site-scope) and [stakeholder-updates](/questions/tagged/stakeholder-updates).

---

As [announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390463/), this site is following an alternate process to the site proposal process in [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com).

A Prompt Design Stakeholder group was created. This group started collaboration on a Stack Overflow for Teams instance in the meantime that GenAI Stack Exchange and its child meta (this site) were ready.

Due to the default license for the content created in  SOFT, there were concerns that the result of the site scope discussion held there could be used as is in a help center article. Because of this, they were posted as an [answer to this question](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2/806).

The progress of the Stakeholders group was reported first on Meta Stack Exchange and is now done here. See [stakeholder-updates](/questions/tagged/stakeholder-updates).

---

##### Meta Stack Exchange

- Related tag: [prompt-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prompt-design-site).
- Call to join Stakeholders Group: [Are you interested in Prompt Design? Join the Community Stakeholders group](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390571/)
- Stakeholders updates on MSE: [GenAI (previously Prompt Design) site stakeholder group updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391232/)

Comment: I suggest using [meta-tag:scope] instead of [meta-tag:site-scope] because the first, in combination with [meta-tag:discussion], has been used on [se] on +6k questions, while the second on less than 300.

Comment: What are the  legal reasons?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, and this is not legal advice. @FranckDernoncourt The Help Center on-topic page was created in SOfT. I don't think SOfT is Creative Commons licensed (which makes sense, given the target audience). Worse, a CM can't likely just make a Meta post where we edit in our individual contributions to that page (to get the content under a CC license) as [the Help Center isn't necessarily complaint with the CC BY-SA 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380622). We're currently awaiting a response from SE Legal on the right way to get SE the licensing they need for this.

Comment: cocomac : According to [What happened with the stakeholder community group the week of July 28th](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/115/12), the site scope is still being discussed. Considering this, please "unaccept" answer to this question.

Comment: @Wicket I can if it’s really needed, but… the point of it being a Community Wiki was so that once we’ve reached consensus via other meta posts, anyone can edit this to have the updated scope. My intention was for us to get consensus via questions, and then have this as an "official-ish reference" for what is on-topic, so I’d suggest editing it to update it over posting other answers, as the idea is that it can eventually be copy pasted into the Help Center. The accept wasn’t meant to set it in stone.

Comment: As I already mentioned, could you please remove the accepted mark? It's because we are still discussing the scope of the site. Having the accepted mark could make some users think that everything is already decided and that there is no need to add more answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

### What topics can I ask about here?

If you have a question about *prompt design* and/or *using generative AI*, you're likely in the right place. Generally, we welcome questions about:

- **Writing prompts and prompt design**. Questions about writing prompts for tasks, techniques for writing prompts, prompt templates, and why some prompts work better are on-topic. Note that questions seeking specific "ready to go" prompts are *not* on-topic here.
- **Effective use of generative AI tools**. Questions regarding how to use generative AI models to produce high-quality and useful output. This includes but is not limited to, accuracy/correctness, best practices, data preservation, etc.

  - Questions related to using generative APIs are also on-topic, but they must be focused on the use of the model or tool. General API questions and questions related to application or programming issues should be posted on Stack Overflow
- **Questions about the capabilities of tools/resources.** While we allow questions about the features and capabilities of different generative AI tools, these questions must allow for factual, attributable answers. Questions that seek opinions about which tool is better are off-topic. Additionally, if you are affiliated with a tool/product/etc. then you must mention it in your question or answer. Note that having your username, profile picture, or profile about-me text containing your company/product name is *insufficient* disclosure, and you must include the disclosure in your answer. See also [How not to be a spammer](https://genai.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).
- **Questions about the history relating to generative AI tools.** While historical questions about generative AI related content is allowed, be sure to make such question not too broad. The question should be very clear about what it is asking, and the question should not be opinion-based.

**Some questions that don't fit within the scope of this site are:**

- **Questions asking for "ready to go" prompts**. On GenAI, questions should seek explanation. Off-the-shelf prompts on specific topics tend to be unhelpful for others, become obsolete quickly, and generally aren't a good fit for the Stack Exchange Q&A format.  Besides, there's a lot of flexibility when interacting with AI, and specific prompts will produce different results each time they are used.
- **Questions with potential illegal or dangerous uses**. We typically assume good intentions and take a default stance that most generative AI tools have both acceptable and problematic uses. Questions about prompting generative AI models to either produce illegal output or provide directions on engaging in criminal activity are categorically disallowed. While we require that all questions follow the Stack Exchange [Code of Conduct](https://genai.stackexchange.com/conduct), we also prohibit questions asking for assistance with creating output that would violate the CoC.
- **Questions regarding the internal workings of generative AI models**. This site is for asking about *using* them - if you're interested in the development of those models, consider [AI SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/tour), [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/tour), or [Cross Validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).
- **Questions seeking a list of resources/tools.** Lists of resources attract spammy and subjective/opinionated answers, and are hard to keep up-to-date, so questions that request a list of tools or resources are off-topic here.
- **Questions discussing ethics of a scenario**. Questions asking for judgement calls on whether a given use of a generative AI tool is ethical are off-topic. This policy is largely because they rarely have objectively correct answers and tend to be more opinion-based and subjective.  Consider [Philosophy SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.
- **Questions about specific legal matters**. These questions are off-topic on Gen AI. While users generally contribute answers in good faith, the answers are not legal advice, and contributors here are not your lawyer.  Consider [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

---

"What should the /help/on-topic page say?" by cocomac is licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0

"What should the /help/on-topic page say?" by Brian H. is licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0

"What should the /help/on-topic page say?" by Rebecca J. Stones is licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0

Comment: Is it commonly understood by the broad community interested in generative AI that generative AI systems and generative AI models are the same as generative AI tools?

Comment: If you want to make questions about generative AI off topic, it might be a good idea to rename the site to 'generative AI use' or something. (Imagine that on photo.SE would make questions about making photos off topic and try to be only about using photos in other places )

Comment: @DavidMulder see [Let's clarify the site's name to "GenAI Users"](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/105/1103).