# Should questions regarding the inner workings of a GenAI system be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

In many cases, an understanding of what's going on under the hood makes it *much* easier to:

- get a system to do what you want it to;
- understand why it's not, and how to fix it;
- understand when you're using the wrong tool for the job;
- identify things that should *theoretically* be possible, even if you don't know how to prompt the system to do them.

However, *technical* questions about AI can (depending on the question) be better suited for:

- [Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/)
- [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)
- [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)
- [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Should questions regarding the inner workings of a GenAI system be on-topic?

Answer (score 4):

Questions focusing on the *practical consequences* of AI implementation details should be on-topic, because they are relevant. This should include theoretical questions, provided that they have clear and obvious practical implications for the use of GenAI systems – even if they would be on-topic on other Stack Exchange sites. Such on-topic questions include:

- [Why is Generative AI so bad at Chess?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/13/10)
- What makes fingers so hard?
- How can Bing Chat look stuff up?

Questions that don't tie back to using GenAI systems to generate stuff are off-topic. Such off-topic questions include:

- How do I know whether my model is overfit?
- Do images need to be normalised before training a latent diffusion model?
- Why are transformer models more powerful than Markov models?

This kind of policy is in line with other Stack Exchange sites – notably that of Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange; to quote [their `/help/on-topic` page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Below you can find a *non-exhaustive* list of specific topics that are considered on-topic here. Next to each topic, you have links to other stacks where the corresponding topics may also be on-topic.

Thirteen other sites are listed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hard question because **the new name of the site "Generative AI Stack Exchange" and the scope we decided upon for "Prompt Design Stack Exchange" are mismatched.**  And now we have users who weren't on Teams joining in the discussion afresh here on meta.GenAI, perhaps bewildered as to why we would even need to ask a question almost equivalent to:

> Is genAI on-topic at genAI.SE?

We've recently changed the site name to "Generative AI" and now we face a far broader range of questions about generative AI than we've previously envisaged, such as [How important are GPUs vs CPUs when training an LLM](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/5/26) which asks about hardware requirements for training a GenAI, a topic that is miles away from anything we discussed when the name was "Prompt Design".  We never even asked "Is GenAI training on-topic?" because it was blatantly off-topic at Prompt Design.

We have two important considerations here:

- **The name of the site should largely match the scope of the site**.  I do not want to be the one who closes good-faith questions about generative AI at *Generative AI Stack Exchange*, while simultaneously trying to keep experts from leaving ("hey, I wanted to answer that!").
- **Do we want to compete with AI.SE?**  I don't feel like this would benefit either site.

We wanted a site focused on ***using* GenAI**---it was our niche that didn't overlap much with other sites.  However, the name "Generative AI Stack Exchange" does not signal GenAI usage.  **We don't really have a "using GenAI" site anymore.**

Imagine a GenAI expert writing a textbook called "Generative AI"---this textbook's content is what people are going to naturally think are on-topic at *Generative AI Stack Exchange*.

There's a Daoist concept called 无为 ([wuwei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_wei), or "non-doing") focused on achieving harmony through taking the path of least resistance.  Assuming changing the site name a second time is off the table (right?), the path of least resistance is to **change the scope we agreed upon previously to match the name of the site** so we're not spending our upcoming years fighting against a tide of genAI-related yet off-topic questions.

And now finally to answer the question:

> Should questions regarding the inner workings of a GenAI system be on-topic?

**At a site called *Generative AI Stack Exchange*, they have to be on-topic, otherwise it will be too illogical for users to understand.**  I'm acutely aware that this is [not what we agreed upon](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-is-on-topic-on-genai-se) for *Prompt Design Stack Exchange*.  I'm also acutely aware this is going to negatively impact both GenAI.SE and AI.SE, such as by making it hard for experts to know which site to use.

Nevertheless, we probably should still declare off-topic low-level, implementation questions about line 351 of `my_genai_v3.2.1.cpp`.

Comment: I agree that “How do I edit the Llama 2 source code to”-type questions should be off-topic. I don't think “competing with [ai.se]” should be much of a concern; pretty much every one of their questions is on-topic somewhere else, yet they're doing just fine.

Comment: Ah, they're just random examples.  I want to focus on the forest, not the trees.

Comment: [Changing the site's name again is _not_ off the table.](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9573600#9573600)

Answer (score -2):

I think further fracturing the sites is a bad idea, and these questions should remain off-topic here. (Already *where* to suggest asking them instead is tricky...)

To your lead-in though, I agree. A question here whose answer is easiest to understand by knowing what's going on under the hood should ideally get an answer that *links to* such an under-the-hood description, maybe a Q&A on one of those related sites.

Comment: This reasoning seems to contradict [the reasoning for jargon being allowed](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/10). Do you have thoughts on that?

Comment: Of the two examples currently there, I'm not sure whether they'd be well-received elsewhere.

Comment: An answer on this site might explain what a neural network is, and the implications of that on some aspect of a particular system. An answer on, say, [ai.se], would probably take for granted that people understood what a neural network was.

Comment: I don't think it wise to have the same Q&A in two places, with one A just explaining every fourth word in a new paragraph.  That's what new questions (or likely, already-existing ones) are for.  If there's an entirely different take on the Q, that's a bit different.  (Another push for https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/829685...)

Comment: That's the usual policy for cross-posting (i.e., don't go 'round posting _duplicates_, but if you're after a different take / angle / aspect, feel free); traditionally, we haven't had it affect scope discussions too much (from what I'm aware). But it _is_ worth saying again.

Comment: The question is, what questions about genAI that are already on topic elsewhere would lead to _better_ answers from/for a different audience here, and does that outweigh the downsides (including information seekers needing to search yet another site, prospective answerers needing to keep track of another site, splitting reputation, inability to flag duplicates that _don't_ have that beneficial "local angle").