# Is jargon on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

Inspired by [What is a GenAI (Generative Artificial Intelligence) tool?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/3/10) – do we want questions about the meanings of words?

If so:

- Do we need some kind of notability criteria?
- What sorts of words can we define here?
- What kinds of evidence should we permit for answers? (*Should* we have explicit, global standards on this?)

Comment: it wouldn't be new. Ex [the music fans site](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the previous answers<sup>[1](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/12), [2](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9/12)</sup> that we should allow questions about GenAI jargon.

As background, it's worth mentioning that allowing questions as jargon is not new in public Q&A platform communities. Here are some [discussion]s previously held across the Stack Exchange network, including `jargon` in the question title ([[discussion] title:jargon](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdiscussion%5D%20title%3Ajargon)):

- [How do SE sites handle domain-specific jargon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165656/1359324)
- [Questions asking for technical terms/jargon](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/479458)
- [Is asking questions about Christian jargon appropriate here?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4417)
- [Should we have a jargon policy/guideline?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/52)
- [Do we have a jargon problem?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/535)
- [What should our general opinion be on jargon?](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/q/70)

Instead of defining *words* we should focus on *terms*. The difference is subtle but meaningful.

Not all the questions about *words* mentioned in GenAI publications should be allowed; we should only ask about words or phrases that don't have the same meaning in other contexts.

The term should have appeared in a **public, notable and permanent publication**, including this site's tour and help center articles. Questions about terms used in "paywalled" publications and casual conversations should not be allowed. The OP of such questions should be pointed to ask the question to the responsible party of such publication.

---

As of July 19, 2023, the related local tags are

- [vocabulary](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary)
- [terminology](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)

SO and SE sites have:

- [terminology](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bterminology%5D%20is%3Aquestion) > 36k questions
- [vocabulary](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bvocabulary%5D%20is%3Aquestion) > 6.5k questions
- [word-meaning](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bword-meaning%5D%20is%3Aquestion) > 5.5k questions
- [jargon](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bjargon%5D%20is%3Aquestion) < 300 questions
- [glossary](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bglossary%5D%20is%3Aquestion) < 200 questions

Comment: The scope limitation in your last paragraph is good, but I think it's a bit strict: “casual conversations” _can_ include vague, woolly terms, but it can also include colloquial-but-precise language.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 The idea is that there should be a public record that could be retrieved someway. Casual conversations might be challenging, as words might be accidental / circumstantial.

Answer (score 4):

I think it should be on-topic as well. There are words that I still do not understand in this field, and I would like to see/ask about them here to get the answer (the knowledge I am seeking). This particular kind of questions should be categorized into a single tag though IMO. For example, `jargon` tag.

In addition, the words are likely to be finite (even though new words are going to be coined in the future); therefore, there will be questions about them and this is a good opportunity to be the knowledge silo about this.

Comment: Currently we have [tag:vocabulary] and [tag:terminology]

Comment: @Wicket Should we have only the [tag:terminology] though? Why do we really want to have [tag:vocabulary]? It sounds like it is a tag for [ELL.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) and [ELU.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=vocab).

Comment: It's too early to know if we need both tags. Vocabulary is used in several applied fields. I disagree with limiting it as a tag to only the language sites.

Comment: @Wicket Now I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

I too asked a jargon question [here](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/7/26).  I think it should be regarded as on-topic.  If we're trying to help people use GenAI (and GenAI.SE) then they're going to need to know what the relevant jargon means.  Judging from what I've seen on Reddit, there's lots of jargon, buzzwords, and technical terms being coined, and it's likely people need help with this.

Comment: I didn't mean "accept" in that sense; I've clarified the question.