# Eeek! The scope we chose for Prompt Design doesn't match a site called Generative AI Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, site-scope, site-name

Over at the Teams, we carefully considered what should be [on/off-topic](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/26) at *Prompt Design Stack Exchange*, but now we have *Generative AI Stack Exchange*.

Users will come to the site and ask generative-AI questions which we didn't consider, or were previously considered off-topic at *Prompt Design*.  It seems users will come in fairly large numbers as site is made public, perhaps outnumbering the stakeholders; they will ask and answer questions,  up/down-vote, vote to close, and participate on meta, without being privy to the Teams discussion.  There are questions that are obviously off-topic at *Prompt Design*, but naturally on-topic at *Generative AI*.

This has the potential to divide the community: stakeholders think the scope is A (because that's what we agreed upon), but everyone else thinks its B (because it says *Generative AI* on the door).

So...

- Do we need to rethink the scope, topic by topic, for the site *Generative AI Stack Exchange*?
- Do we want to expand the scope of *Generative AI Stack Exchange* so that genAI questions are generally on-topic?
- Do we really want to the heartache of closing various generative-AI questions off-topic at *Generative AI Stack Exchange*?
- Should we change the name again?  (*PromptAI Stack Exchange* seemed reasonable.)
- Is it possible to pause the site launch, and go back to the Teams and first sort this out?

Comment: well, we're still in beta. site scope is still not set in stone. I wouldn't sweat making changes to what's considered on/off-topic.

Comment: I agree with starball. This is still in beta. It is the perfect place and time to make things proper.

Comment: I can confirm that this phenomenon will happen. I heard about the private beta and came to ask a test question based on my understanding of scope from the Meta.SE posts unaware of any SOfT discussion. I was surprised to find a comment under my question stating it was off-topic.

Comment: related: [Let's clarify the site's name to "GenAI Users"](/q/105/33)

Answer (score 4):

We *should* re-think the scope, topic by topic. We can do this by asking and answering questions on meta with the [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag, and making sure that we vote on them.

There's no need to go back to the Teams instance, because this is the usual process of deciding a site's scope. We should treat our `/help/on-topic` draft as a living document, reflecting the current consensus described in meta. (If that consensus is *obviously wrong*, write an answer to the relevant question.)

Comment: The Voting feature in the public Q&A is a terrible way of making decisions. I'm afraid I have to strongly disagree with using this feature for taking scope decisions in the current conditions. I.E., [What reputation requirements, if any, should we alter](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/59/12), [Do we want a prompt design site or a generative AI site?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/12)