# Is it just me, or is voting currently wild at GenAI.SE?

Tags: discussion, voting

- [To what extent can GenAI be used for content moderation?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/59/to-what-extent-can-genai-be-used-for-content-moderation) (+3 / -4)
- [How can I draw three cups in a row, the middle one blue, the outside ones red, and with one red cup taller than the other two cups?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/66/how-can-i-draw-three-cups-in-a-row-the-middle-one-blue-the-outside-ones-red-a) (+3 / -3)
- [If I use a GPT add-on in my spreadsheet is my data still private or it can be leaked to other GPT users](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/55/if-i-use-a-gpt-add-on-in-my-spreadsheet-is-my-data-still-private-or-it-can-be-le) (+5 / -3)
- [How can I extract the embedded prompt configuration from AI-generated images?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/46/how-can-i-extract-the-embedded-prompt-configuration-from-ai-generated-images) (+5 / -3)
- [How to train Bard to answer based on a private FAQ document?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-to-train-bard-to-answer-based-on-a-private-faq-document) (+3 / -2)

Judging from the voting, you might expect these to be controversial questions, yet they're all literally about using GenAI.  It seems you're almost guaranteed a downvote for any question you might ask, no matter how good it is, no matter how much effort you put into it.

- [How long is a "token"?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/34/26) (+5 / -5)

This one is asking to understand the usual usage of the term "token", and it's got 5 downvotes and was even closed.

- [How important are GPUs vs CPUs when training an LLM](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/5/26) (+3 / -5)

This even got a fairly good answer, and after being upvoted initially, is now being downvoted.

Yesterday, I got a "serial voting reversal":

> [image: reversal +6 Voting corrected (learn more)]

So...

**Question**: Is it just me, or is voting currently wild at GenAI.SE?

Comment: I agree, it's a wild ride. I think it's a combination of 2 things, downvote at 1 rep and very strong opinions about GenAI and what people should ask in this community.

Comment: I noticed [two users](https://genai.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) with 20+ downvotes (on 61 posts at the site) who have signed the [strike letter](https://openletter.mousetail.nl/).

Comment: ^ Note: since the posting of this meta question, the votes have been reverted and thus also removing the users from the Voters page.

Comment: If you suspect that a specific user is engaging in serial/targeted voting, please flag one of their posts for moderator attention with a custom flag explaining the situation. (The CMs will be handling these flags initially, until mods can be elected.) Alternately, if you're unable to raise a flag (e.g. the user doesn't have any posts on the site), you can contact staff using the [Contact](/contact) form at the bottom of the site. Either way, please include as much relevant info as you can, to make it easier to look into the situation.

Comment: Thanks it's been resolved now.  Initially I didn't realize the cause, but for a while we were getting 2 or 3 unexplained downvotes per post.  Hence this post.

Comment: There's been a lot of things upvoted that I personally feel would deserve downvotes on any other SE site, based on their quality--eg unsupported claims with no citation or examples. To me, those deserve a downvote.

Comment: The question was asked during the private beta (before the site was advertised).  Questions were consistently getting 2 or 3 unexplained downvotes, no matter what they asked.  This voting behavior was affecting scope-related decision making.  This has been resolved now.

Comment: Voting behavior is somewhat personal, and we benefit from a plurality of voting styles.  I personally tend to think of good answers getting a score of 10+ (cf. the [nice answer](https://genai.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer) badge), and a score of 1 or 2 is fairly low, quite "meh" indeed.  But if you want to downvote unsupported claims, then there's nothing more to say other than: thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 4):

Is this surprising? Not at all.

When users were posting their nominations for the stakeholder group, some users received this now-removed comment (still visible in the [Meta Stack Exchange Comment Archive room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9551335#9551335))

> It's **deeply** disappointing to see early and vocal supporters of the strike so eager to jump on the bandwagon. Ideally Spencer's question would've gone unanswered until the end of the strike. It feels like when the CEO said the company's genAI efforts have community support he was right after all. It makes me wonder who I am striking for.

When I pointed out this felt quite rude, *other* users (let's assume no sock was involved) jumped in to protect the first one.

So, basically, you have multiple users agreeing on hating the fact that other individuals dared to think they were free to do what they wanted with their life and join a site.

... And now you are telling me that the site is under a serial downvote targeted attack? As I said, I would not be surprised at all if this was proven to be true.

Answer (score 2):

I have felt the voting is wild here for some time, especially with the downvotes. I am not sure if it is because the threshold is low or people here just want to really express what they feel. Voting have rules, but people are gonna vote from their heart anyway. There may be many factors at play here, which I cannot identify them all. However, I don't think it is all too bad of a situation. I see this as a phenomenon where we can really measure if this site can live through an era full of disagreements.

I too casted some downvotes in this site as I see fit, which is what I usually do on SO. I now see that the impact of downvote here is immense because of currently low population in our community here. It is, more or less, intimidating when your post gets a downvote. [One of my questions](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/22/why-chatgpt-assume-that-i-do-not-know) has not been received well either, and I accept those downvotes because I want to know if this kind of question is acceptable in the community. Now it has a standard for this kind of question on the site, and that my goal is achieved.

So, no, it is not just you. Voting is currently wild here at GenAI.SE.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a post on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391527/1359324) criticizing [a GenAI Meta post](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/59/12). Also, a message in a private channel from Meta Discussion, a Discord Server, criticizes one of my posts in GenAI.

The SO/SE community has some people that hate anything coming from the company and others who hate anything related to GenAI; others don't like the process of this site. Also, others are pushing in favor of allowing GenAI answers, etc.

So far, it looks to me that only a few have come and voted.

Reference

- [Is there an external space dedicated or strongly related to Stack Exchange Community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389721/1359324)