# Can "prompt design" (experts = power users) and "generative AI" (experts = genAI developers) coexist here?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

In front of us is the genAI.SE chessboard.  We want to make the best possible moves, regardless of how we got in this position.

I mentioned [here](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/26) and [here](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/26) how the current [on-topic](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/26) document doesn't pay much attention to generative AI, and indeed declares a fair chunk of generative AI as off-topic (such as [inner workings](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4/26)), which is incompatible with a site called *Generative AI*.

With the aim of promoting harmony...

**Question**: Can "prompt design" (experts = power users) and "generative AI" (experts = genAI developers) coexist here?

If not, I fear a kind of "civil unrest", with both sides competing for dominance (although it seems [recent voting anomalies](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/84/26) were for other reasons, and some have been reverted, so maybe it's not as bad as I first thought).  I would also argue that many "power users" are interested in how genAI works.  And perhaps genAI developers are interested in how users use genAI.

If we can agree on this, then we can get to work rewriting the on-topic page---generative AI should not seem like an afterthought on a site called *Generative AI*.  And it's very hard to reach a consensus on whether or not XYZ is on-topic if we all have totally different visions for the site.

(If we can't agree, maybe we need two sites, or maybe change the name of this site to e.g. "PromptAI" or "GenAI tools", and migrate the perfectly good generative AI questions to AI.SE.)

Comment: Doesn't "generative AI" as the title imply that it's about using genAI, not developing it, similar to how "Unix and Linux SE" is primarily about using, not creating, Unix-like OSes?

Answer (score 3):

I think [SirBenet's answer](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/93/26) clarifies a lot.  As nice as it is to wish to "coexist", there are some concrete reasons not to:

- The people who were motivated to join the *Prompt Design* are more on the user side of things.  We are avid users of a range of genAI software, websites, apps.  This is what we're passionate about.
- Even with the best intentions, we simply might not have the expertise to create a site of interest to genAI developers.  We might not be able to tell if an answer is good or bad.  We might not be able to competently moderate such a site.
- There are already multiple Stack Exchange sites where genAI developers can go, such as [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [AI Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/).  (Maybe we should make an actual list, like this meta post I made at Chinese.SE: [Alternative Stack Exchange sites for "not really about the Chinese language" questions](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1665/8099).)  While many sites' scopes overlap ([Movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) and [SciFi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)), it's better to avoid directly competing (e.g. duplicates).

While it seems we need a scope broader than "prompt design", we simply are unable to include every conceivable generative AI topic.

It seems we should stick to a "experts = power users" site, and next look into ways of better communicating that to users.