# Let's clarify the site's name to "GenAI Users"

Tags: feature-request, site-name

This is not really my idea; I first saw it in [SPArcheon's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391614/what-was-it-like-being-a-genai-se-stakeholder#comment1309224_391615) (+10), then in [SirBenet's answer](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/93/26) (+6).  But...

**Proposal**: Let's clarify the site's name to "GenAI Users"

Since we probably don't want major changes to the site shortly after the WeAreDevelopers event, basically for now this means changing the banner name (which I managed to do through editing the html):

> [image: GenAI Beta banner changed to GenAI Users Beta]

> [image: GenAI Meta banner changed to GenAI Users Meta]

And the [list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions) page

> [image: List of sites]

Importantly,

- the favicon doesn't need to change;
- the URL doesn't need to change;
- and from a marketing perspective, this change can be explained as a "clarification" or "move fast and break things" rather than e.g. "rebranding" or "whoops, we made a mistake".

Maybe there's other changes Stack Exchange's design team would need to do that I'm unaware of, but the most important visual change is to put the word "Users" in the banner.  The rest can probably wait.

The precedent here is [Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/) (url `android.stackexchange.com`):

> [image: Android Enthusiasts screenshot]

I thought about [coexisting with developers](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/91/26), but it just doesn't work.  SirBenet's diagram has helped me in a lot in getting a mental picture of what we should be working towards:

> [image: a Venn diagram with "GenAI usage" and "GenAI development"]

Having "Users" in the banner gives fair warning for those wanting to ask questions here.  And there's still wiggle room for questions about e.g. OpenAI or inner workings (which may be of use and interest to genAI users), which are not directly about using genAI.

It basically solves the [scope-title mismatch problem](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/26).  And it resolves my issue of moderation, where I envisage genAI developers coming to the site and asking e.g. about training their models.  And if (power-user) mods attempt to explain to genAI developers (who are quite possibly experts) that their questions are off-topic, it may come off as rude or arrogant, or at the very least, illogical.

Comment: Considering that the logo and related design details are very simple, as the sites, parent and child (meta), use the Beta theme, I agree with it as a quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 10):

Support the idea, and would also suggest possibly expanding it further to "Generative AI Users":

[image: "Generative AI Users" mockup]

For comparison, a non-exhaustive list of some other sites that have different short names (in URL) to long names (in banner, site list):

| Name | Long-form name |
| --- | --- |
| ru | Stack Overflow на русском |
| gis | Geographic Information Systems |
| english | English Language & Usage |
| diy | Home Improvement |
| scifi | Science Fiction & Fantasy |
| android | Android Enthusiasts |
| gamedev | Game Development |
| cs | Computer Science |
| webapps | Web Applications |
| japanese | Japanese Language |
| mechanics | Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair |
| *genai* | *Generative AI Users* |
| *genai* | *GenAI Users* |
| *genai* | *GenAI* |

Long-form names lean towards being written out in full rather than using abbreviations, except where it's part of an existing product name ("Tor") or very common ("TV" and "OS" are fine, "AI" is probably fine)

"Generative AI" may be clearer for those unfamiliar with GenAI, at least to get the general gist. A user in chat also raised possibility of GenAI being mistaken for gen*eral* AI (though I think that's usually abbreviated AGI).