# Confusion in "Get previews and early access..." and "alpha-testing signup?"

Tags: discussion, support

From StackOverflow, taking the [Behind the scenes with the folks building OverflowAI (Ep. 594)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/28/behind-the-scenes-with-the-folks-building-overflowai-ep-594/?cb=1) where the Notes encourage you to "sign up to be an alpha tester [here](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/)" which takes you to Labs. The two buttons on Labs are: "Get previews and early access ..." or one that leads to "Contact Sales".

Intuitively the "early access" button would seem to be the one discussed in the prior page for alpha-testing signup - but that part is unclear.

I'm happy to help test, primarily to see if all the new AI search hype can help the C/C++ and Bash/Shell, etc.. "Related" links finally actually be "related" to the question asked. However, I don't want to have my SO interface changed so I'm permanently stuck with the new enhanced features.

Will the "early access" alpha-testing be completely separate from my current SO user-interface, or will it become part of it? If the latter, will there be a way to turn it off and simply revert to the current user-interface (which I'm rather fond of). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I assume that you think GenAI.SE is OverflowAI, correct? To clear things up GenAI.SE is not OverflowAI, it's a different project.

Comment: That is where some of the confusion is coming from. I was under the impression that the request was for help in testing/using/evaluating the new AI tools that SE was rolling out and implementing. My confusion comes from the "Announcing Overflow AI" link in Top-Right of the SO page. Following that I'm led to the link above and to the GenAI community. My goal was to help test/evaluate the tools as they apply to SO and my concern is it is unclear what the buttons that I'm presented with will actually do for/to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was [mentioned by Henry WH Hack v3.0](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/confusion-in-get-previews-and-early-access-and-alpha-testing-signup/125#comment224_107), to get the clarifications that you are looking for, the proper place for your post might be either [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) or [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com), but since this place is about questions about GenAI SE, it's "off-topic" here.

Let's start with the local primary purpose. This is a Meta for the site currently named [GenAI Stack Exchange](https://genai.stackexchange.com); the site name is not definitive and might be changed. Currently is an open [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to change the site name: [Let's clarify the site's name to "GenAI Users"](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/105/12), among other things, to prevent any misunderstandings similar to the one that prompted your post here.

This site is part of what used to be named "Stack Exchange", while https://stackexchange.com still exists, the "Stack Exchange" looks to be in a state which Google calls "maintenance mode": It's being kept operating, but Stack Overflow, Inc. is not actively developing it anymore. "Stack Exchange" used to be the company name; nowadays, the company name is "Stack Overflow", like the Q&A community founded by Joel Spoelsky and Jeff Attwood in 2008, https://stackoverflow.com. The URL of the company is https://stackoverflow.co. Please note that the company URL uses the `.co` instead of `.com`.

The recent https://stackoverflow.blog posts use the term "public Q&A platform", so this place is part of it.

To learn about the recent announcements, read the recent posts at https://stackoverflow.blog. It might also be helpful to go directly to https://stackoverflow.co/labs/.

Some questions should be answered by the sales team, not by the community of the "public Q&A platform". I also think that should not be answered by the "Community Management Team", but they might be answered by people having the "Staff" badge. The Community Management Team also has the "Staff" badge, but they have a diamond too.

Comment: *"https://stackexchange.com still exists, the "Stack Exchange" looks to be in a state which Google calls "maintenance mode": It's being kept operating, but Stack Overflow, Inc. is not actively developing it anymore"* Could you please elaborate this part? Is there an announcement about the end of https://stackexchange.com?

Comment: @A.L No announcement; the company is not investing money in improvements, just keeping it running. They are not been using "Stack Exchange" in their blog posts recently; instead, they say "public Q&A platform", as if the platform that supports +180 sites were a generic / brandless product.

Comment: Well, that answers my question that there was at least a reason for my confusion. The name change game is one that may look good on paper, but rarely ends well. (as a lawyer practicing for nearly 3 decades, I've seen many in my time) Sorry for the question on the wrong site, as explained, I thought I was following links to get to where I could help QA the use of some LLM enhanced search for StackOverflow.com with hope that it would finally improve the "Related" links attached to questions. (which now could be title "Unrelated" :) Thank you for the answer, I understand better now.