# Are questions asking about the APIs for GenAI services on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I just came across this question: [Can third-party ChatGPT plugins see requests we send to ChatGPT?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/112/can-third-party-chatgpt-plugins-see-requests-we-send-to-chatgpt) Is this question on-topic for GenAI SE? Or, more generally, are questions about specific APIs for GenAI services on-topic here?

After reading [What is on-topic on GenAI SE?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2/1184), at first glance it seems like they are not. On one hand, APIs are an integral part of interacting and developing with GenAI, and thus on-topic. However, API usage questions aren't really about GenAI itself and would seem like a better fit for Stack Overflow (not sure how the wider Stack Overflow community would feel about this though, as they have been quite hostile towards ChatGPT-related questions in general).

Personally, I think allowing these questions to be on-topic and giving them somewhere to be asked would be beneficial, but a question that boils down to "How does this API work?" might attract duplicate and low-quality questions.

Comment: Welcome to GenAI Meta. Did you know we have the tags [tag:api] and [tag:code]? Still, their tag wikis might need work.

Answer (score 2):

My first glance on [the question](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/112/can-third-party-chatgpt-plugins-see-requests-we-send-to-chatgpt) gave me the urge to call close vote on the question, but after I read the question and the [What is on-topic on GenAI SE?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-is-on-topic-on-genai-se/2#2) page back and forth a couple times I think the question is really on-topic as is.

Here is what I interpreted. Emphasis mine.

> Questions related to **using** generative APIs are also on-topic, but they must be focused on the **use** of the model or tool. General API questions and questions related to application or programming issues should be posted on Stack Overflow

The question is basically asking if the 3rd party can see the data we send through it. This alone is really not focusing on the **use** of the model or tool.

However, here is what I think is important. From my perspective, as a user of generative AI, this question gives me knowledge that is useful to me (future visitor) such that I will always remember not to put any credentials or secret information into 3rd party that connects to any GenAI tools. That is how it affects the use of GenAI tools.

Well, as a person in IT field, I know that it is always insecure to send sensitive data or credentials to 3rd party agent in all cases, but we should not assume that every visitor in GenAI site has that knowledge in mind. This question will provide this beneficial information to the public.

Finally, questions that has no connection to the use of generative AI or its model/tool should still be off-topic as stated above. We should leave those parts to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [AI.SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/).