# Are questions asking for recommendation on-topic? In such case what are our guidelines for such questions?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, asking-questions

Several public question-and-answer platform communities have norms to close questions asking for recommendations, while others allow them.

What is our stance about asking for recommendations, and if they should be allowed, what are the guidelines?

##### Asking Recommendations

- [Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com).
- [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

##### References

- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

  - [How should I ask about getting a software recommendation?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2180/494724)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

  - [What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254393/21769175)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com).

  - [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/1794161)
- [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com).

  - [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3705/311306)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than relying on a rule that was copy-pasted from a different QA site, how about rating the actual usefulness of such questions and answers in our context?

One of the biggest challenges in generative AI is to know the right tool for the job. Few people know all tools in a particular domain of generative AI.

[Which image generating services don't duplicate copywritten work?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/questions/270/which-image-generating-services-dont-duplicate-copywritten-work) is a useful question (with clear requirements) that has attracted a great answer.

If we chose to accept such questions, I recommend having strict rules about them:

- Questions:

  - Must be about a very specific real-world use case.
  - Must have very clear requirements:

    - Does the solution need to be open source, or gratis, or less than X$/month?
    - Are you looking for a solution with a web UI? With an API? Or is some source code or binary? Is a research paper with no implementation enough?
- Answers:

  - Must address each and all of the question's requirement, with a yes or no.
  - Should be about one particular solution, rather than linking to a repository of potential solutions.

Disclaimer: I am a moderator on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), which welcomes such questions and has proven very useful.

Comment: I agree with most parts of the answer, but I have a different opinion regarding assessing [Which image generating services don't duplicate copywritten work?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/270/12). Also, I'm afraid I disagree with using the answers as part of a question evaluation; each post should be evaluated independently of others. Still, questions might be improved considering what was learned from the answers, while the new question revision doesn't invalidate the answers.

Answer (score 0):

As it is currently written in [What is on-topic on GenAI SE?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-is-on-topic-on-genai-se), it is off-topic.

> **Questions seeking a list of resources/tools**. Lists of resources attract spammy and subjective/opinionated answers, and are hard to
> keep up-to-date, so questions that request a list of tools or
> resources are off-topic here.

This applies to questions asking for recommendations.

Comment: Not all questions asking for recommendations require a straight list of resources; the guidance on sites like Super User explains how to ask these questions to prevent "subjective/opinionated answers".

Comment: @Wicket It looks to me that the guidance just suggests to change the question from **asking for recommendations** to **asking the actual problem**, which is perfectly fine. I still stand by what I answered here though.

Comment: While I understand that there is a common understanding that asking for "recommendations" implies asking for a list of tools or resources, considering the broadness of our potential answer, I think it's not appropriate to say "they are off-topic". In the coming weeks, I may provide a more detailed response to this question.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Nicolas Raoul's answer to make recommendation questions on-topic here.

Additional arguments:

- Answers to recommendation questions don't have to be subjective/opinionated.
- It's not atypical for an answer to a non-recommendation question to become outdated.
- Other AI sites such as stats.SE and DS.SE are also ok with some recommendation questions.