# Is the "'ffhq-dataset-v2.json' with Automatic1111" question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, specific-question

This question [How do I correct the "No such file or directory: 'ffhq-dataset-v2.json' with Automatic1111](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/306/26) was closed as:

> This question does not appear to be about GenAI, within the scope defined in the [help center](https://genai.stackexchange.com/help).

I don't understand; it seems like a user is trying to get genAI to do something, which is basically what the whole site is about.  The only thing I can think of is that it's a bit technical, but I don't recall anyone suggesting technical questions are off-topic.  (Things like editing source code, yes.  But getting software to work?)

**Question**: Is the "'ffhq-dataset-v2.json' with Automatic1111" question off-topic?

- I'm just now noticing large numbers of Automatic1111 questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=automatic1111).
- There's another "I can't use genAI because of a technical issue" question here: [ComfyUI error on PixelTiledKSampleUpscalerProviderPipe](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/329/26)

Comment: Related: [Why AUTOMATIC1111 is named like this?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/179/12)

Answer (score 3):

### Programming issues are off-topic here

Quoting [this answer on *What is on-topic on GenAI SE?*](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2/1103) (emphasize mine):

> #### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> - Effective use of generative AI tools. Questions regarding how to use generative AI models to produce high-quality and useful output. This includes but is not limited to, accuracy/correctness, best practices, data preservation, etc.
>
>   - Questions related to using generative APIs are also on-topic, but they must be focused on the use of the model or tool. General API questions and **questions related to application or programming issues should be posted on Stack Overflow**

This question is a programming issue, so it's off-topic on Generative AI.

Comment: I'm wondering if we should point users to ask for a site recommendation on [meta.se] as there are specific questions about "programming" that is not well received in [so]. In this case, the OP might get the help that they need on [su], [opensource.se], [cseducators.se] among other sites.

Comment: I don't think it's about programming; the OP doesn't seem to be writing their own software, but getting someone else's software to work properly.  What gives you the impression it's about programming?

Comment: Although it does seem to fit under "application issues", so maybe that's the reason (?).  I wonder though... if e.g. ChatGPT was giving an error message, whether we'd consider that off-topic.  It seems we haven't explored this topic enough.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Let's start talking about the current revision ([4](https://genai.stackexchange.com/revisions/306/4)). It's unclear as to what "software" the OP is referring to. Assuming that they are using [Stable Diffusion web UI](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui), this is not software like the ChatGPT apps (Web, Android, iOS). This software requires the user to follow the instructions to be installed. There are several sets of instructions, i.e., run batch scripts,  install Python and other components that to be able to install the software, among others.

Comment: The install instructions are documented in a Readme.md file hosted in GitHub, a platform mainly intended to be used by software developers, including programmers.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones fair point, the OP of the other question has a warning error when running the program. It looks like it may be fixed by configuring or patching the software, that would be a programming question then. Or it may be fixed by changing the parameters in the UI, then that would be an end user solution. Both ways would still be off-topic if we follow the text I quoted.

Comment: @Wicket, sorry, but you've not understood the question, this isn't a dig at you, just an observation that you seem to be unfamiliar with the AI engine that is being discussed here. It's called Stable Diffusion, it's a very well known image generation engine that can be run from an server using any one of a number of web based interface, or run locally using API. This question is about operating the engine through n API, API questions are specifically on topic, they're just spoken about in other terms.

Comment: @A.L, the problem is with an API call from the engine, which is on topic, otherwise about half of the questions posted on this site would be off topic.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR: Yes, it's off-topic.

The question concerns an error thrown by an application software delivered as open-source code requiring computer-using and programming knowledge and skills. The root cause of the problem looks to be a programming issue that might or might not be prevented by an application software end-user without programming knowledge and skills.

---

As explained in [A.L's answer](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/174/12), questions about programming issues are off-topic in GenAI Stack Exchange.

If this site were to allow all questions about GenAI tools that are distributed on platforms like GitHub, the "question" lacks enough details, and it might be required to be split into multiple posts. The OP could require a lot of guidance on using GenAI Stack Exchange and the corresponding application software.

One of the risks of going deep into improving this "question" is that it might be required a lot of back and forth. Unfortunately, the public Q&A platform doesn't facilitate this kind of interaction. Also, the chat platform doesn't look like that will facilitate working with the OP on improving the question.

The OP should clarify the steps to reproduce the problem. One important step to clarify the problem is correctly identifying the application software used because

- *Automatic1111* is a **GitHub username** having 37 GitHub repositories.

  [image: Automatic1111 GitHub user profile]

  <sup>Source: https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111. Taken: August 13, 2023</sup>
- *Automatic1111* has several repositories related to Stable Diffusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the person who closed it might not have understood the question.

I've found similar things on other stacks where people will vote to close based on thinking that a question is about something completely different, like people closing a question on math\stats because they mistake a question about the statistical method for a question about whatever the subject of the data used in an example is (Like closing a question that uses baseball stats as an example because they think that it's a question about baseball, not stats).

Stable Diffusion is definitely on topic as it has a tag, and there's nothing in the scope documentation saying that you that the technology behind the image generation is off topic.

Surely this stack isn't just about input-output?

Comment: The question was not closed by a single person. The post-close notice shows that were multiple persons who voted to close it.

Comment: Do you think it'd help to add screenshots to show the usual operation of this software?

Comment: @Wicket, yes, but you made yourself known, and were asked multiple times to explain your reasoning, and in response you posted a link to a blanket landing page but would not say which part of the page you were referring to. You stated that you wanted me to change the question, but could not define how or why, so please withdraw your vote on principle, or provide the information necessary to meet your expectations.

Comment: @Rebecca J. Stones, it's console based, providing the text from the console is better because people can cut and paste from it, which they can't do with a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for opening this discussion; I have suggested to OP to do it several times. The OP insisted on asking directly to me as if they hadn't understood the standard workings of the public question and answer platform and, more specifically, how the closing questions work.

As mentioned in [a previous answer](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/172/12), the post-close notice shows multiple users voted to close the question. Considering this, the argument that the question was closed because a single user misunderstood the question doesn't look to sustain.

The original revision of the question was about general problems related to using open-source code. The later revisions have not made significant progress clarifying that the question is a good fit for GenAI tools.

Questions about general problems with using open-source code are off-topic on GenAI Stack Exchange; in other words, questions on this community should be about using GenAI Tool features, i.e., questions about using Stable Diffusion on a web browser might be on-topic, but troubleshooting like questions that require to:

- validate the user's computer meets the system requirements,
- that computer has the required components and they working correctly
- that have installed an open-source code project
- and debugging programming errors

are off-topic in this community.

Questions on this community should meet the standard public question and answer platform norms depicted in the GenAI Stack Exchange tour, help center and meta posts tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

The OP and others interested in the question should focus on understanding the GenAI Stack Exchange's:

1. Topic and scope
2. Workings

Some comments focused on reopening the question as if the site were a service desk that should accept any support request question, keeping the question with minimal changes.

Considering the GenAI Stack Exchange's stage, I think that one of the branches of this conversation should be focused on improving the question independently if, in the end, the question stays closed.

Another branch might be how to handle posts that might require back and forth beyond the standard use of comments.

Comment: You seem reticent to put this information against the question.

Comment: As stated earlier, you haven't understood the question. As has been demonstrated on many occasions people will follow the crowd. One person misunderstands a question, so other people come and rather than looking at the question objectively they follow those who went before them believing them to be correct. Your own bullets clearly show this as they all depend on an identical the same logical fallacy. My question is clearly and unambiguously a specific engine operation question, which is on topic by your own links.

Comment: Rather than trying to shoe-horn the question into an off topic category, maybe you could suggest what needs changing so that the desired outcome can be achiever in an on topic category.