# What guidance could we give to non tech savvy people struggling with using GenAI tools distributed through GitHub an alike plafforms?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Some GenAI tools are distributed through platforms like GitHub. Non-tech-savvy people might find the public Q&A platform hard to get started with and might find it hard to find where and how to ask for help when struggling with a GenAI tool problem.

One very popular tool is referred to by some users as *Automatic1111*, but this is a GitHub username, not a tool. In a particular context, it might be preferred to use *Automatic1111* instead of "Stable Diffusion Web UI" because there might be other tools with similar names or other reasons.

Pointing users to Stack Overflow, Super User, Web Applications Stack Exchange, or another site might be correct but ineffective if the asker doesn't know how to ask a question according to the public Q&A platform standard norms.

If they are fortunate, they might get answers before the question is closed. Below there are some cases:

##### [OpenAI ChatGPT gives a network error at long responds. How can I fix it?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38268/74276)

It was posted in Artificial Intelligence SE, migrated to Stack Overflow and Web Applications and rejected by both sites. Currently, it's closed.

##### [How can non-coders use programs on Github?](https://superuser.com/q/1444103/1794161)

It was posted in Super User. Currently, it's closed.

##### [Automatic1111](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=automatic1111%20is%3Aquestion&searchOn=3) questions in Stack Overflow

There are 30 questions on Stack Overflow with the word Automatic1111. Of these questions, very few are well received and answered; only two questions have a score of +2 and are answered.

#### Related

- [How to help new users to get started with GenAI SE?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/155/12)
- [Is the "'ffhq-dataset-v2.json' with Automatic1111" question off-topic?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/171/12)

#### Reference

- [Why AUTOMATIC1111 is named like this?](https://genai.stackexchange.com/q/179/12)

Comment: "this is a GitHub username, not a tool" ...today I learned. (0_0)